# Python multiprocessing gradually increases memory until it runs our

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I have a python program with multiple modules. They go like this:

1. Job class that is the entry point and manages the overall flow of the program
2. Task class that is the base class for the tasks to be run on given data. Many SubTask classes created specifically for different types of calculations on different columns of data are derived from the Task class. think of 10 columns in the data and each one having its own Task to do some processing. eg. 'price' column can used by a CurrencyConverterTask to return local currency values and so on.
3. Many other modules like a connector for getting data, utils module etc, which I don't think are relevant for this question.

The general flow of program: get data from the db continuously -> process the data -> write back the updated data to the db.

I decided to do it in multiprocessing because the tasks are relatively simple. Most of them do some basic arithmetic or logic operations and running it in one process takes a long time, especially getting data from a large db and processing in sequence is very slow.

So the multiprocessing (mp) code looks something like this (I cannot expose the entire file so i'm writing a simplified version, the parts not included are not relevant here. I've tested by commenting them out so this is an accurate representation of the actual code):

```
class Job():
    def __init__():
        block_size = 100 # process 100 rows at a time
        some_query = "SELECT * IF A > B" # some query to filter data from db

    def data_getter():
        # continusouly get data from the db and put it into a queue in blocks
        cursor = Connector.get_data(some_query)
        block = []

        for item in cursor:
            block.append(item)
            if len(block) ==block_size:
                data_queue.put(data)
                block = []

        data_queue.put(None) # this will indicate the worker processors when to stop

    def monitor():
        # continuously monitor the system stats
        timer = Timer()
        while (True):
            if timer.time_taken >= 60: # log some stats every 60 seconds
                print(utils.system_stats())
                timer.reset()

    def task_runner():
        while True:
            # get data from the queue
            # if there's no data, break out of loop
            data = data_queue.get()
            if data is None:
                break

            # run task one by one
            for task in tasks:
                task.do_something(data)

    def run():
        # queue to put data for processing
        data_queue = mp.Queue()

        # start a process for reading data from db
        dg = mp.Process(target=self.data_getter).start()

        # start a process for monitoring system stats
        mon = mp.Process(target=self.monitor).start()

        # get a list of tasks to run
        tasks = [t for t in taskmodule.get_subtasks()]

        workers = []
        # start 4 processes to do the actual processing
        for _ in range(4):
            worker = mp.Process(target=task_runner)
            worker.start()
            workers.append(worker)

        for w in workers:
            w.join()

        mon.terminate() # terminate the monitor process
        dg.terminate() # end the data getting process



if __name__ == "__main__":
  job = Job()
  job.run()
```

The whole program is run like: `python3 runjob.py`

Expected behaviour: continuous stream of data goes in the `data_queue` and the each worker process gets the data and processes until there's no more data from the cursor at which point the workers finish and the entire program finishes.

This is working as expected but what is not expected is that the system memory usage keeps creeping up continuously until the system crashes. The `data` i'm getting here is not copied anywhere (at least intentionally). I expect the memory usage to be steady throughout the program. The length of the `data_queue` rarely exceeds 1 or 2 since the processes are fast enough to get the data when available so It's not the queue holding too much data.

My guess is that all the processes initiated here are long running ones and that has something to do with this. Although I can print the pid and if I follow the PID on `top` command the data_getter and monitor processes don't exceed more than 2% of memory usage. the 4 worker processes also don't use a lot of memory. And neither does the main process the whole thing runs in. there is an unaccounted for process that takes up 20%+ of the ram. And it bugs me so much I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I don't see how this works at all given that `data_queue` seems to be locally defined in each method.

Comment: @Booboo Maybe in this simplified version the OP meant `self.data_queue` each time?

Comment: @quamrana You *could* be right, but generally you simplify your post by removing extraneous functions and methods. But to go to the to the trouble of removing `self.` all over the place just to make the code completely wrong, I really don't understand why anyone would do *that*.